# Prove $\sum \frac{t}{(1+y)^t }= \frac{y+1}{y^2}$

Tags: summation, finance

I see on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+t+from+0+to+infty+t%2F%281%2By%29%5Et) that $\sum \frac{t}{(1+y)^t} = \frac{y+1}{y^2}$ when t goes to infinity. I cannot, however, proove it myself. What theory is used and how do I start the proof?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms

Comment: Why I put the finance tag, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_duration#Macaulay_duration often $PV_i=\frac{coupon}{(1+r)^i}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall from Geometric series, we have
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} x^t = \dfrac1{1-x}$$
Differentiating both sides, we obtain
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} tx^{t-1} = \dfrac1{(1-x)^2} \implies \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} tx^{t} = \dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Plugging in $x=\frac1{1+y}$, we obtain what you want.